# specific systemctl service is stopped after daily apt upgrades and clean activities

Tags: ubuntu, cron, systemd, apt, acpi

I have problem in multiple servers (it happened twice, one per month) where starting `Daily apt upgrade and clean activities` for some reason stops my specific service and then never starts it, so it is turned off and then I need to start it manually.

In syslogs I see this:

```
Mar  7 06:59:24 server systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Mar  7 06:59:38 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  7 06:59:38 server systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Mar  7 06:59:38 server systemd[1]: Stopping Odoo 11...
Mar  7 06:59:39 server systemd[1]: Stopped Odoo 11.
Mar  7 06:59:39 server systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar  7 06:59:39 server systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
Mar  7 06:59:41 server systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Mar  7 06:59:42 server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
Mar  7 06:59:45 server systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
Mar  7 06:59:45 server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar  7 06:59:45 server systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar  7 06:59:51 server systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Mar  7 06:59:59 server systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
```

As you can see from log, when it starts that, it also starts ACPI event daemon, which then stops `Odoo 11` service, but this service stays stopped, even though it should not be.

And here is systemd config for Odoo 11 service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Odoo 11
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=odoo
Group=odoo
SyslogIdentifier=odoo11
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo11.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Maybe something wrong with systemd start-stop service config? Though if I run that service myself, it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to to use `Wants=` with your PostgreSQL service dependency instead of `Requires=`.

With `Wants=`, your app won't be stopped just because PostgreSQL was stop/started for a software upgrade.

Read about the distinction more in `man systemd.unit`.